# Visualizing all Sentinel-1 Images in collection using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

Here is the code. There are 81 sentinel images but I am only seeing the first one (or the last one maybe), how can I visualize other images. Let's say I want to see the 2nd one ?

```
// Importing S-1 Images
var S1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD");

// Importing Geometry (area of Interest)
geometry = 
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[74.38065032641738, 12.778968253582836],
      [74.38065032641738, 7.612293582692355],
      [77.74246673266738, 7.612293582692355],
      [77.74246673266738, 12.778968253582836]]], null, false);

// Define Time Interval 
var start_date = ee.Date('2018-07-21');
var end_date = start_date.advance(3, 'month');
var date_filter = ee.Filter.date(start_date, end_date);

//Display of Image 
var collection2 = S1
    .filter(date_filter)
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filterBounds(geometry);
var vis_params2 = {bands:'VV', min:-25, max:5};
var label2 = 'SAR Backscatter';


// Visualizing the map
Map.addLayer(collection2, vis_params2, 'secondimg')
Map.centerObject(geometry);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an `ee.ImageCollection()` to the Map, you see the [Mosaic](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_composite_mosaic) of the imagecollection. Note that there is no single date of acquiring a mosaic image- it is a synthetic image composed of the latest available image for each pixel in a queried geometry.

If you want to specifically obtain the nth image in an imagecollection, convert it to a list and plot only the nth element of that list like so:

```
var n = 50;
var imageList = collection2.toList(n); //convert image collection to list
var image = ee.Image(imageList.get(n-1)); //obtain nth image from 0 indexed list
// Visualizing the map
Map.addLayer(image, vis_params2, 'nthImg') //add nth image to Map
```

Again, note that since Sentinel-1 doesn't have a fixed acquisition mode over India, the nth image may or may not cover the entire `geometry` you queried.

[Link to corrected code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7b833d4b27e837fe234c9fff2276fb00)

Comment: Thankyou. I got the concept now :)

Comment: Thanks. a follow up question 
How can I change tohe label of the image (Lets say I am looking for 2nd image and I want its label as its date of acquisition.

Comment: Use `var image = image.set({"system:id":image.get("system:time_start")})`